I have a 2016 ram 1500 that the cooling fan only comes on when the ac is running i replaced the radiator filled and got all air out but still no fan
I have looked for relays and any wires that would be damaged or cut but found nothing

There should be a coolant temperature sensor, its wiring and t-stat that may be faulty.
